# Dismissing UIViewController in UIAlertController Action causes a crash

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have just a simple UIAlertController and I show it by a button click:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: NSLocalizedString("Are you sure you want to log out?", comment: ""), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Out", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction) in

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // CRASH
}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And I want to dismiss my controller with this dialog actions.

So when I click on "Sign Out" button in Alert I get app crashed.

**Crash log:**

Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/UICollectionViewData.m:435
2018-02-23 00:11:17.741531+0300 App[4681:1373962] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', **reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'**

BUT! I don't have CollectionView in this controller at all.

**NOTE:** If I use just a simple self.dismiss(...) without this alert actions, then my controller got dismissed as normal.

**NOTE 2:** Controller that I want to dismiss is a SplitViewController and I don't have any CollectionViews.

**NOTE 3:** I present my SplitViewController just in a simple way using self.present(splitVC, animated: true)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the presenting view controller of that SplitViewController?

Comment: That's weird, I tried to reproduce here..no luck. It looks like you have something in your view hierarchy. The view that will appear right after the dismiss has the collection view ?

Comment: @theCoderGuy UIViewController with CollectionView.

Comment: @GIJOW Yes, it has a collection view. But, I've tried one more time with the same setup and VC's without UIAlertAction and it works as expected.

Comment: Yes I understand... just trying to figure your environment. Do you have any code on `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` in this view where you have the CollectionView ?

Comment: Just a guess at this point, but it looks like UIKit is re-drawing the part of the collection view that was under the alert at the same time as your code trying to dismiss the VC holding the collection view. Try wrapping your `dismiss` line to force it onto the main (UI) thread: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }`

Comment: @GIJOW. No, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are empty (just super... call).

Comment: @DonMag Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: OK - hmmm.... are you sure that, *inside the closure*, `self` is referring to your VC, and not to the AlertVC itself?

Comment: @DonMag, yeah, I'm sure about it. I just tried to see what's going on in debug session and I got my view controller as a self reference.

Comment: Try calling `dismiss` on the alert itself maybe?

Comment: @HunaidHassan and what I should get after this? Alert just closing and that's it.

Comment: I am guessing both UIAlertVC and your VC try to dismiss at the same time. iOS doesn't allow 2 transition animations in parallel. Try this `alert.dismiss(animated: true) {self. dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}`

Comment: @atereshkov Would you mind showing us the code from your presenting VC?

Comment: @HunaidHassan in that case nothing happens at all.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) cases the same crash.

Comment: Can you share more code? Ideally the whole vc?

Comment: Eventually, I found the problem. I'll post it as an answer. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.

This crash was caused by layoutAttributesForElements. My cache array wasn't cleared and when layoutAttributesForElements get called crash appears.

If you have a custom CollectionView layout, then you should always clear a cache in prepare() of UICollectionViewLayout.

```
override func prepare() {
     cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
     ...
}
```

So that was the problem.